# Showing images on my homepage using the data from my Django Model

Tags: python, django

Would like to simplely show multiple pictures from my model data that I inputted via the `Admin` in my template file between the `UL` tag. I am having trouble rendering the data to show the image. I dont need to route anything in `URL.py` yet, just need to pollute the images on my homepage first. Can someone please help troubleshoot my issue? Thank you!

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)    
    color_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    size_types = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2, blank=True,default=0.00) #To show original price if, new price has been added
    product_tags = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for product tag area')
    novelty = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    product_website = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True) #To show other sites to Users, where they can purchase the particular product
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products/main',max_length=100, null=True) #For the argument upload_to, will add to the static folder and generated image will be stored in suing that path specified
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.')

  #This shows when each item was uploaded & by who, to the User 
    uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  #For Admin Purposes, to track and see which if still active by for administrative users only
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    #Foreign Keys & other relationships
    designer = models.ForeignKey(Designer)
    boutique = models.ForeignKey(Boutique)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)

    #Metadata
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Product")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Products")

    #Helps return something meaningful, to show within the admin interface for easy interaction
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.name)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms

from django.forms import extras, ModelForm

from products.models import Designer, Product, ProductCategory, Boutique

class DesignerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Designer

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

class BoutiqueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Boutique

class ProductCategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategory
```

**Views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseForbidden
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from django.contrib import auth, messages
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site
from django.shortcuts import render

from products.forms import ProductForm, ProductCategoryForm
from products.forms import BoutiqueForm
from products.forms import DesignerForm

from products.models import Boutique, Product, ProductCategory, Designer


class ProductView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = "task"
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "site_base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <ul id="tiles">
            <li>
                {% for task in products %}
                    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/product/main {{task.image.url}}" />
                  {% endfor %}
            </li>         
         </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some odd things in this code.

Firstly, you want to do something with all products. So why are you using a DetailView, which is for selecting and displaying a *single* item? You need to use a ListView, which will pass a list of products.

Secondly, for some reason you override `context_object_name` to be "task". But then in the template, you iterate through "products" - a name that is not provided. If you've called the context object "task", that's what you should be iterating over.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! Based on this advice, I was able to troubleshoot the issue!

Answer (score 0):

**Figured out what I was doing wrong!**

Apparently I needed to go within my urls and change my already existing `TemplateView` in the first `url tuple`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
url(r'^likes/', include('likes.urls')),
)

  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and change the `URL tuple` to a `ListView`, to generate the image from my django models.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import ListView
from products.models import Product

from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", ListView.as_view(
        template_name="homepage.html",
        model = Product,
        context_object_name = "products",
        ), name="home"),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
    url(r'^likes/', include('likes.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```